# MPI processes causes pthreads to execute sequentially

Tags: pthreads, mpi, hybrid

I wrote down an MPI/pthread hybrid code and I execute it on a cluster. Specifically, I compile it using mpicc -lpthread and launch 2 MPI processes on different nodes (6 nodes total, with 8 cores per node) using mpirun -np 2 -bynode and then create 8 threads on each node. However, the threads do not execute in parallel and they follow a sequential execution?

Parts of my code:

```
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
        MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &len);
        // more code between these..
        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &sort, (void*) arrays[0]);
        pthread_create(&thread_id2, NULL, &sort, (void*) arrays[1]);
```

Comment: how do you determine that the processes are not executed in parallel?

Comment: i used the sched_getcpu() function, and all threads returned 0

Comment: what happens, when you specify the affinity with [`sched_setaffinity`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html)?

Comment: arleady tried that, cluster wouldnt recognise CPU_SET nor CPU_ZERO though i included <sched.h>, define _GNU_SOURCE and compiling it using -D__USE_GNU..

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem, i just used a latest version of mpicc and it's all okay now

Comment: I doubt it.  You probably got lucky due to some configuration change.